# Node.js: How to create pluggable Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-management-system, pluggable

I'm going to create a CMS in Node.js and Express i have a folder structure like below:

- MyCMS

  - **plugins**
  - themes
  - uploads
  - index.js

i want to load plugins from **plugins** folder:

- plugins

  - sample-plugin
  - awesome-plugin

i want to know how to make my CMS pluggable?

what is best way to make an application pluggable?

and then how to load plugins?

(i need a plugin system at all)

**EDIT**: As i said, i need a plugin system like wordpress. wordpress has hooks (actions and filters), is it best? how to implement it?

Comment: what is there? i need a plugin system. a pattern or a design guideline with code examples.

Comment: i googled it but i was found some things but i don't know anything. do you can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a plugins folder as NPM essentially does this for you. You then maintain a list of npm packages that are officially supported. You could look at Ember-CLI and see what they do with their 'ember install' and specific packages for Ember.

Comment: This is good idea. i'm thinking about publish plugins in npm and use them in CMS. but i want to know how to do it?

Comment: google "npm publish" for the official npm docs on publishing packages - after that you'll just need to do npm install 'package-name'

Comment: Hi. i know how to publish package, but i don't know how to specific packages in node_modules folder.